# Spring MVC 3 - Reset Model after a form submit failure

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC3 application and I am trying to understand how can I reset the values in a form backing model after a form submit has been posted.

- For example, consider an application that displays the information
  about a customer and their services (referred to as "Review" page).
- There are 2 edit links in Review page, one to modify the profile
  information of a customer ("Edit Profile") and another to modify
  their selected services ("Edit Services").
- "Edit Profile" has a Submit and Cancel button

Here's the scenario in which I might need help to update the model with the last successful submit.

1. Customer clicks on "Edit Profile" and changes their profile (say change name,phone) and clicks "Submit".
2. There a no server side validation errors and the model gets updated with the most recent info and "Review" page is good.
3. Customer again clicks on "Edit Profile" and tries to change another part of profile (say email) and clicks "Submit".
4. This time, there is a server validation error ("email is already taken by another user") and customer is brought back to "Edit Profile" page. However since the form was submitted, invalid email appears on the "Edit Profile" page (which is expected).
5. Now, customer clicks on "Cancel" button in "Edit Profile" page.
6. User is directed back to "Review" page with the invalid email (as the form backing model was updated with the submit that was done in Step 3).

My question, is how can I update the model when users clicks "Cancel" on the "Edit Profile" page to the most recent successfully submitted form.
I cannot pull it back from database as customer might have done successful submits before running into the validation error.

Thanks,

Comment: You mention that the data is not stored in the database after a successful submit, so where is the data persisted then (my guess is in a session)? You should populate your model with data from that location.

Comment: Put your model object into session after step 2, then you can revert changes using this object in step 5

Comment: Customer Data is one of the @SessionAttributes. However, it was not tracked in a HttpSession. The ModelAttribute gets automatically updated upon form submission. I can try to also store it in session after a successful submit. Thank you both for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you have a set of stateful pages that you would like to process in sequence before everything is ready for a single submission that updates the database? If that is the case, you may consider to use [Spring Web Flow](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think the page design allows to click any of the "Edit" links in the page and hence an order cannot be enforced. Moreover, this scenario is part of an existing application that does not implement webflow. So, I am afraid, I will not be able to convert this app to webflow, just for this requirement.